# A good way to encrypt database fields?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, django, encryption

I've been asked to **encrypt various db fields within the db**.

Problem is that these fields need be decrypted after being read.

---

I'm using **Django** and **SQL Server 2005**.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah. Tell whoever told you to get real. Makes no / little sense. If it is about the stored values - enterprise edition 2008 can store encrypted DB files.

Otherwise, if you really need to (with all disadvantages) just encrypt them and store them as byte fields.

Comment: @tomtom : It makes sense if you design a system using symmetric encryption where an user can only decrypt and read his info stored in a DB using his password. This is how they do with ldap based records.

Comment: No, normally it makes zero sense - unless you program something like LastPass. it ESPECIALLY makes zero sense if the key is available somewhere on a server (the web server). This is a total nieche issue, with hugh negative impact (search goes out of the window).

Comment: Because it is. In 099% of the time encrspting the fields is a totally senseless thing to even start with.

Comment: @tomtom : yeah, correct about the lastpass! I forgot to mention, if you are writing a single-sign-on something similar to lastpass, it make sense, where you store user's all password encrypted using user's own key.

Comment: And that pretty much is it - password repositories where you explicitely do not want to trust even your local application. Any other scenario is mostly (99%) hogwash - people (mostly from management) asking for something without knowing what they do. SQL Server file encryption handles the "discs get stolen" side very well (and is sometimes legally a good advantage) but encrypting fields IN the database has serious implications (like loosing query capabilities).

Comment: @tomtom : correct! It happens, When we do not know what the threat is :-)

Comment: What about SQL injection? Field encryption can at least protect some sensitive information from that.

Comment: Encrypting fields does make sense! It avoids leaking data in SQL dumps or backup files. Just don't rely on this alone, make sure other security threats are also mitigated. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16939/is-it-generally-a-bad-idea-to-encrypt-database-fields

Answer (score 8):

See: [Using Symmetric Encryption in a SQL Server 2005 Database](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131038/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022107-1.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and created the following solution: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2489/

I happened to use M2Crypto as the cipher engine, but that can be swapped out if desired.

As TomTom notes, doing this just raises the bar for an attacker rather than making hostile decryption impossible - in addition to accessing your database, they now also need to access wherever you store the passphrase that feeds into the key derivation function. However, by splitting the key from the data it is protecting in this way, you at least now have the option to further secure that key (e.g. with a key management server) to raise the bar yet higher. Defence in depth is a good strategy, but you also need to decide what constitutues overkill for a given application.

It's also a terrible idea to encrypt any field that might be useful for searching or sorting purposes (I only use this trick to store OAuth credentials for a web service that doesn't support proper tokenised OAuth connections).

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing things like passwords, you can do this:

1. store users' passwords as their SHA256 hashes
2. get the user's password
3. hash it
4. List item

check it against the stored password

You can create a SHA-256 hash in Python by using the `hashlib` module.

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately I need to fully decrypt them

Comment: @RadiantHex do the columns involve passwords? Those don't have to be decrypted to do password checking. Otherwise, you may want to consider doing some RSA encryption before storing the value.

Comment: Decrypting passwords -- a security nightmare.

Comment: @S.Lott that is why I actually use sha+salt for my passwords :)

Comment: @RadiantHex: Please **update** the question if this encryption/decryption business involves or does not involve passwords.  The question is unclear.  The comments make an assumption.  Only **you** can provide **facts**.  Please clarify.

Comment: This is terrible advice. A salt + SHA256 hash is not sufficient to protect a password. A slow hash function is essential. Use Argon2, or at the very least scrypt.