# Storing sensitive data in database, recommendation

Tags: python, database, postgresql, security, passwords

I'm searching for best solution to store sensitive data in database.
I know that this is common problem and i have done my homework (at least this is what i think), but i wanted to ask here before i will make a decision.

Assumptions:

- Encrypted data needs to be decrypted. We are talking about SMTP credentials like username, password, host, port itp.

I was thinking about 2 concepts:

1. Encrypt data with help of passlib.totp library. To make those data a bit safer i will keep key in separate file. Then from what i can see i can use this library to decrypt data to plain text using my key.
2. The other concept was to encrypt and decrypt data during query request with help of postgres:

   ```
   insert into demo(pw) values ( encrypt( 'data', 'key', 'aes') );
   ```

   And:

   ```
   decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes'), 'utf-8')
   ```

   Here the key will be stored also in separate file.

So my questions are:

1. What is better approach to encrypt / decrypt data, in code or in database?
2. Are there any better (stronger) libraries to use than passlib.totp -> i have no experience with that library (i'm aware that encryption / decryption is not the moste secure way of storing password -> password supposed to be hased but i need it in plain text to use users smtp gate).

Comment: Ask yourself a question: against what kind of threat is this going to protect you? Because apparently if someone gains access to your system, the key can be compromised as well as the database contents…

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of that. However if someone will gain access only to database content ex by sql injection (as a result of weak protection of input fields) then i think this will give those data a bit of protection. I'm fully aware that it's not 100% solid bullet prof concept. Than again, for example you have employees to whom you want to give access to read data base (or part of it) but you don't want to allow them the see password in plain text, they don't have access to file structure. So I'm thinking that there are scenarios where this can be usefull.

Comment: Always encrypt and decrypt client side. People could  read your network traffic otherwise for plaintext . This isn't exactly completely programming related, so move here https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @cricket_007 - assuming the author wants to use those credentials to perform some background task, your advice cannot be applied here.

Comment: Well, among other things this does help with backups not being insecure when outside of your system.  Plus, some countries have legislation on the obligations in case of a data breach/loss and differentiate between encrypted and un-encrypted.  Perhaps this is a better question for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A good way to encrypt database fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3979385/608639), [How can I encrypt data in mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24624459/608639), [Best Way to Encrypt Customer Information in My Company's MySQL DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9265877/608639), [How to store private encrypted user data in the database, but make them available to other chosen users?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7529582/608639), etc

Comment: This seems like the biggest problem in your design: *"... the key will be stored also in separate file..."* They keys to the encrypted data probably need to be in protected storage; and not lying around on the filesystem. You should also consider prompting the user for some additional entropy (a.k.a., a password) to add to the secret in protected storage. You should also familiarize yourself with how an OS provided KeyChain works, and how to use it effectively. Also see Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

> 2) The other concept was to encrypt and decrypt data during query request with help of postgres: insert into demo(pw) values ( encrypt( 'data', 'key', 'aes') ); and decrypt(pw, 'key', 'aes'), 'utf-8') Here the key will be stored also in separate file.

I wouldn't recommend that, because it's *way* too easy for the keys to get exposed in `pg_stat_activity`, the logs, etc. PostgreSQL doesn't have log masking features that would protect against that.

I strongly advise you to use app-side crypto. Use a crypto offload device if security is crucial, so key extraction isn't possible for most attackers. Or require the key to be unlocked by the admin entering a passphrase at app start, so the key is never stored unencrypted on disk - then the attacker has to steal it from memory. But even an unencrypted key file somewhere non-obvious is better than in-db crypto, IMO, since it at least separates the key from the data.

Comment: Thank You. At least i know right now that option 2 is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, your application needs to be able to recover the plaintext passwords using some sort of key. If your system is compromised, you have to assume that the malicious user will simply find your key (whether in the database or on disk) and perform the exact same decryption that your application performs.

When your system needs to store passwords in a recoverable form, i.e. to authenticate with external systems, at best you can only obfuscate that information. This is what people mean when they refer to "security through obscurity", and it's a bad idea.

When you give the *appearance* of security, without *actually* securing something, then that can make things even more dangerous. You, or other people administering the system, may overlook other important security measures because they believe that there is already a layer of protection for the sensitive information. It can create a social situation where sensitive information may be *more* likely to leak, than it would if it was assumed that the only way to safeguard the info is to safeguard the systems that hold it. It can also cause people to believe that if data is stolen from the database, "maybe it's okay because they can't decrypt it". This is how you end up responsible for leaking credentials to the wide world, because you **must** assume that if your application can get the plaintext data, so can an attacker that has compromised your application.

There may be a **very very small** advantage to encrypting a multipart key on multiple systems (i.e. part on the file system, part in the database), so that somebody who gains access to one system doesn't necessarily gain access to the other. It's reasonable to say that this might, in fact, delay an attack, or deter a lazy attacker. Generally speaking however, the place where your application lives has access to both these things anyway so if your application is compromised then you must assume that the data is compromised. (Edit: You mentioned in another comment you have users who a) shouldn't know the passwords stored in the DB, but b) will have access to the DB directly. Believe me, there is a non-zero chance of one of those users getting all of those passwords if you do this. By going down this path, you're putting your faith in a faulty layer of protection.)

tl;dr reversible encryption when storing sensitive data rarely has *practical, real* security value. If you're trying to tick a compliance check box, and you have no power to overrule someone up the chain who needs you to tick that box, then by all means implement something that "encrypts" the data. But if you're actually trying to secure your system, look elsewhere: here be dragons.

Comment: Thank's any way for spending your time writing all of that. It's hard to not agree with you. But it's not answering my main question at all. The question was: if i must encrypt decrypt (and the reasons are not important why) where it is better to do that in code or trought the db and if in the code what would be the most proper tool for it. That was the main gol of that question. I did not ask "If i should do that or not" -> it's not in the scope of that question at all. But thanks any way, interesting lecture.

Comment: @daveruinseverything The best way to protect your passwords is not to store them :-) Although above answer was made upon an assumption the attacker gains full control over the system. Not being an expert it feels in most cases it's more difficult to get full access from being able to execute your query on the server. In such case would it not be helpful not to store those access credentials in obfuscated form?

Answer (score 0):

You may check [Vault project](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/use-cases.html), a tool for managing secrets:

> **General Secret Storage**
>
> At a bare minimum, Vault can be used for the storage of any secrets.
>   For example, Vault would be a fantastic way to store sensitive
>   environment variables, database credentials, API keys, etc.
>
> Compare this with the current way to store these which might be
>   plaintext in files, configuration management, a database, etc. It
>   would be much safer to query these using vault read or the API. This
>   protects the plaintext version of these secrets as well as records
>   access in the Vault audit log.
>
> **Employee Credential Storage**
>
> While this overlaps with "General Secret Storage", Vault is a good
>   mechanism for storing credentials that employees share to access web
>   services. The audit log mechanism lets you know what secrets an
>   employee accessed and when an employee leaves, it is easier to roll
>   keys and understand which keys have and haven't been rolled.

Vault server stores data in encrypted form. Data can be retrieved via command line or REST API. Server must be in [unsealed state](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal.html) to return decrypted data - unsealing needs specific number of shards of the master key. Once server is restarted, you need to unseal it again.